# Java Web Application File Loader w/ change detection

Tags: java, web-applications, frameworks

Is there any tool/framework available to load and autommatically reload an arbitrary file from within a java web application?

(I'd like to avoid writing it myself - I do know how to write it)

Answer (score -1):

I know [JCAPS](http://www.sun.com/software/javaenterprisesystem/javacaps/index.jsp) has this capability in its file JCD.